# PGFplots: bar plot with color bar

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, color

I am trying to make a 2D bar plot with the bars coloured according to another third variable using the colorbar i.e. the color of the bar has nothing to do with the variables shown but some other variable.

I have previously managed to get a scatter plot with the colours matching but am unsure how to fill the bars with the appropriate colour.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usepgfplotslibrary{colormaps}

\pgfplotsset{colormap access=direct}
\tikzset{mycolor/.code={\pgfplotscolormapdefinemappedcolor{#1}}}

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[colorbar, colormap/jet,
colorbar style={
            ylabel={Years},
            ylabel style={anchor=west, text width=3cm, rotate=270},
        },
    width=15cm,
height=9cm,
    legend style={at={(0.5,-0.15)},
      anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
    xlabel={$x$},
    symbolic y coords={A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L, M},
    ylabel = {$y$},
    xtick={0,5,10,15,20,25,20,35},
    xmax=35,
    xmin=0,
    ytick={A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L, M},
          bar shift=0pt,
    ]

\addplot+ [xbar, point meta=\thisrow{years}, 
    visualization depends on={\thisrow{years} \as \myvalue},fill= mapped color]  table {
    x       y     years
    22.6   A      1.800
    31.7   B      1.300
    4.8    C      2.000
    16.7   D      2.300
    3.9    E      4.100
    0.244333 F    0.61
    3.622143 G    9.1
    0.566104 H    57
    2.98 I       29.8
    1.85 J        3.7
    0.334255 K    6.7
    1.9 L         38
    0.395 M        0
  };

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

So in this picture, "G" should be blue but "I" should be green.

Thank you in advance :) and apologies if the answer is really simple.

Comment: Hello ! It seems your question is related to [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/116765/particular-bar-plot-with-pgfplots-bar-color-category)

Comment: Hey, thanks for the comment, appreciate it. Just trying to adapt it now but I'm not sure as for those solutions the colour was related to the value shown on the plot; I'll update my question to be clearer. Thank you though :)

Comment: I just reopened this question. If this is a duplicate then IMHO 95% of the open questions are.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Jake's solution #1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/116773/194703), which [BambOo linked to](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/537323/pgfplots-bar-plot-with-color-bar#comment1357576_537323), almost one-to-one if you replace the symbolic coordinates by `\coordindex`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usepgfplotslibrary{colormaps}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    colorbar, colormap/jet,
    colorbar style={
            ylabel={Years},
            ylabel style={anchor=west, text width=3cm, rotate=270},
        },
    scatter,
    scatter src=x,
    only marks,
    clip mode=individual,
    scatter/@pre marker code/.append code={
            \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=true,/pgf/fpu/output format=fixed}
            \pgfmathsetmacro\negheight{-\pgfplotspointmeta}         
            \fill [draw=black] 
             (axis direction cs:0,0.3) rectangle (axis direction cs:\negheight,-0.3);
            \pgfplotsset{mark=none}
        },
    xmin=0,
    width=15cm,
    height=9cm,
    legend style={at={(0.5,-0.15)},
      anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
    xlabel={$x$},
    %symbolic y coords={A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L, M},
    ylabel = {$y$},
    xtick={0,5,10,15,20,25,20,35},
    xmax=35,
    xmin=0,
    ytick={0,...,12},
    yticklabels={A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L, M},
  ]
  \addplot table[x=x,y expr=\coordindex] {
    x       y     years
    22.6   A      1.800
    31.7   B      1.300
    4.8    C      2.000
    16.7   D      2.300
    3.9    E      4.100
    0.244333 F    0.61
    3.622143 G    9.1
    0.566104 H    57
    2.98 I       29.8
    1.85 J        3.7
    0.334255 K    6.7
    1.9 L         38
    0.395 M        0
  };
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

With symbolic coordinates it is probably also doable but more efforts.

**ADDENDUM**: Here is one way to spell out [BambOo's great idea](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/537323/pgfplots-bar-plot-with-color-bar/537356?noredirect=1#comment1357728_537356).

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usepgfplotslibrary{colormaps}
\pgfplotsset{/pgfplots/colormap={jet}{rgb255(0cm)=(0,0,128) rgb255(1cm)=(0,0,255)
rgb255(3cm)=(0,255,255) rgb255(5cm)=(255,255,0) rgb255(7cm)=(255,0,0)
rgb255(8cm)=(128,0,0)}}
\newsavebox\JetColorBar
% convert 'hot' -> \result 
\pgfplotscolormaptoshadingspec{jet}{12.5cm}\jetresult
% define and use a shading in pgf: 
\def\tempb{\pgfdeclarehorizontalshading{tempshading}{1cm}}% 
% where '\result' is inserted as last argument: 
\expandafter\tempb\expandafter{\jetresult}% 
\sbox\JetColorBar{\pgfuseshading{tempshading}}%
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    colorbar, colormap/jet,
    colorbar style={
            ylabel={Years},
            ylabel style={anchor=west, text width=3cm, rotate=270},
        },
    scatter,
    scatter src=x,
    only marks,
    clip mode=individual,
    scatter/@pre marker code/.append code={
            \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=true,/pgf/fpu/output format=fixed}
            \pgfmathsetmacro\negheight{-\pgfplotspointmeta} 
            \clip
             (axis direction cs:0,0.3) rectangle (axis direction cs:\negheight,-0.3);
            \path  (axis direction cs:\negheight,0)
             node[anchor=west,outer sep=0pt,inner sep=0pt]{\usebox\JetColorBar};        
            \pgfplotsset{mark=none}
        },
    xmin=0,
    width=15cm,
    height=9cm,
    legend style={at={(0.5,-0.15)},
      anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
    xlabel={$x$},
    %symbolic y coords={A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L, M},
    ylabel = {$y$},
    xtick={0,5,10,15,20,25,20,35},
    xmax=35,
    xmin=0,
    ytick={0,...,12},
    yticklabels={A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L, M},
  ]
  \addplot table[x=x,y expr=\coordindex] {
    x       y     years
    22.6   A      1.800
    31.7   B      1.300
    4.8    C      2.000
    16.7   D      2.300
    3.9    E      4.100
    0.244333 F    0.61
    3.622143 G    9.1
    0.566104 H    57
    2.98 I       29.8
    1.85 J        3.7
    0.334255 K    6.7
    1.9 L         38
    0.395 M        0
  };
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or with `point meta` different from `x`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usepgfplotslibrary{colormaps}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    colorbar, colormap/jet,
    colorbar style={
            ylabel={Years},
            ylabel style={anchor=west, text width=3cm, rotate=270},
        },
    scatter,
    scatter src=x,
    only marks,
    clip mode=individual,
    visualization depends on=\thisrow{x}\as\myx,
    scatter/@pre marker code/.append code={
            \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=true,/pgf/fpu/output format=fixed}
            \pgfmathsetmacro\negheight{-1*\myx}         
            \fill [draw=black] 
             (axis direction cs:0,0.3) rectangle (axis direction cs:\negheight,-0.3);
            \pgfplotsset{mark=none}
        },
    xmin=0,
    width=15cm,
    height=9cm,
    legend style={at={(0.5,-0.15)},
      anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
    xlabel={$x$},
    %symbolic y coords={A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L, M},
    ylabel = {$y$},
    xtick={0,5,10,15,20,25,20,35},
    xmax=35,
    xmin=0,
    ytick={0,...,12},
    yticklabels={A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L, M},
    point meta=\thisrow{years}
  ]
  \addplot table[x=x,y expr=\coordindex] {
    x       y     years
    22.6   A      1.800
    31.7   B      1.300
    4.8    C      2.000
    16.7   D      2.300
    3.9    E      4.100
    0.244333 F    0.61
    3.622143 G    9.1
    0.566104 H    57
    2.98 I       29.8
    1.85 J        3.7
    0.334255 K    6.7
    1.9 L         38
    0.395 M        0
  };
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Based on your proposal, I tried shading the bars with `left/right color=` stuff and with `color of colormap`, but I can never reproduce the colorbar. The idea was to draw a rectangle as large as the axis then clip at the right size to keep the correct colors. But I could not find a way ...

Comment: @BambOo This really just Jake's proposal which I am copying here. So you want to replace each bar by a clipped color bar? Is this what you are trying?

Comment: That is great ! Very nice result, IMHO it is less disturbing that the uniformy colored one

Comment: @BambOo Thanks for the kind words! Thanks to this comment I "discovered" (for myself, of course) the command `\pgfplotscolormaptoshadingspec`. This basically allows one to access all these nice color schemes with Ti*k*Z.

Comment: Yeah, it's seemed useful in such a case, but I am so much confused by these `\def` and `\expandafter` stuff

Comment: @BambOo This is just copied from the manual. (But in this case it really just means that `\jetresult` gets expanded before `\tempb`.)

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat Thanks, this looks great! :) However, it does not colour according to the "year"; for example, H has the years value as 57 but it is blue due to its value on the x-axis when it should be red. The variable A should be blue, when it is orange, because the years value is 1.8. Hope this clarifies and apologies

Comment: @Owen Seems like I misread the question, but this just a trivial switch, see the last part of the updated answer.